# Android TV rendering Webview too large

Tags: android, kotlin, webview, android-tv

I've created a JS webapp that's to be rendered in a webview. In the web preview, the size is fine and the container fits perfectly in the window. However, on android TV, or a TV emulator, it appears to large, with the top of the container clipping the frame and several elements running outside of their parents. In the html, I've set the following meta tags

`content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=5.0,viewport-fit=cover"`

I'm pretty inexperienced with android and android devices so any feedback is greatly appreciated. Attached are some screenshots

[image: in browser]
[image: in emulator (looks same on device)]